# Avoiding node overlaps in semPaths with the "repulsion" argument in the Fruchterman Reingold algorithm

Tags: tree, structural-equation-model, semplot

I fitted a structure equation model with sem and I am now trying to visualize the model with semPaths:

`semPaths(fit1b_rh, "path", "stand",layout="tree", edge.color = "black", residuals = FALSE,  layoutSplit =  TRUE, subRes = 360, asize = 1 , sizeMan = 15,sizeMan2 = 4, sizeLat = 18, sizeLat2 = 7,rescale= TRUE, edge.width=TRUE, asize = 3,  label.scale = TRUE,font = 7, label.prop= .7, overlap = FALSE, nodeLabels = c("HC", "HE","caudalACC","rostralACC","caudalmidfront","parsorb","parstri","rostralmidfront","supfront","age", "sex", "BMI", "suptemp","midtemp","age x HC","age x HE","intemp" , "bankssts","fusiform", "Chronic Stress","ACC","FrontLobe","TempLobe","Interaction stress x age"))`

it works alright so far, but the nodes of my latent variables, as well as some of the nodes of the indicator variables keep overlapping. Sacha Epskamp recommends trying the  Fruchterman Reingold algorithm (layout?) https://github.com/SachaEpskamp/qgraph/issues/5#issuecomment-260288621, but I am not sure how to implement it into my code, simply changing the layout did not work.